# How can I add a namespace to valueObjects using FlashBuilder

Tags: java, apache-flex, blazeds

When I use FlashBuilder to connect to a remote Java object using BlazeDS, FlashBuilder automatically creates a local valueObject matching the object in the remote server.

However, the package name of the remote object gets lost in translation.

Hence if I have two remote Java objects com.foo.A and com.bar.A, I won't be able to distinguish between them in Flex.   So I end up having to name my remote classes com.foo.AFoo, com.bar.ABar.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see why you you can't used com.foo.A on the flex end as well as the java end.  Personally, I think Flex project structure is very different from Java (for instance, Java likes to use DTO naming, while Flex uses Model) and this is why I use [RemoteClass metadata](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/metadata_3.html#198729) to bind the Java DTO to a Flex model.

Comment: Thank you J_A_X.  This is a lower level answer than I was looking for.   I am using Flashbuilder which automatically creates the Flex object that bind to the Java DTO.   So my question was more how to get Flashbuilder to create namespaces that match the DTO namespaces.   In the Flashbuilder generated code I can see that it is using `flash.net.registerClassAlias` to map an object to the Java DTO namespace.  I just need to find a good way of setting up the namespaces in the Flex project model so that I can have more than one Flex class named 'A'.

Answer (score 0):

The Flex class name is not important, and is ignored when sending / receiving classes to / from BlazeDS.

What is important is the name that's specified in the `[RemoteClass]` metadata on your Flex class.

Eg:

```
// Actionscript class Apple.as
package com.mangofactory.sample
{
   [RemoteClass(alias="org.orchard.Orange")]
   public class Apple {
      ... etc ....
```

Here, the Actionscript class `com.mangofactory.sample.Apple` is mapped to the Java class `org.orchard.Orange`

While the naming of the fields & properties within the class *is* important, the actual class mapping is specified explicitly using Metadata.

Comment: Thank you Marty - this is helpful.  As per previous comment I am looking for how to drive Flashbuilder to allow different Flex objects A to map to different Java DTOs.